# Automatically scale to the next level of app service plan in Azure

Tags: azure, autoscaling, azure-app-service-plans

I have a web app hosted in app service in Azure with auto scale out rules defined and it works as expected - when the memory usage reaches the threshold. An VM instance is added automatically

[image]

The problem is that, we discovered that when a new VM instance is added, a new instance of our web app is also added - we do not want this, as our web app is not designed to be horizontally scaled out. We only want one instance of the app.

On Azure portal when I click on Scale up (App service plan), I can only choose another app service plan, it seems to me there is no way I can do something like when a threshold is reached, automatically scale up to the next level of app service plan but keep the number of VM instance.

I am wondering why there is no such option available in Azure?

Or even our conclusion that when scale out, the number of web app instance also increases is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, there's no automatic way to scale up and when you scale out, the number of web app instance also increases.

Comment: thanks. 

If I have multiple instances of my web app. When a request comes in, who will control which instance to handle the request? Do I always need an app gateway or Azure will handle load balancing for me automatically?

Comment: Azure will use a load balancer to distribute the requests across all instances.  Nothing to configure on your side.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no out of the box option for this and that could be because there is a chance to have latency issues during the scale up / down operation and Azure might want the consumer to make this decision consciously. Having said that, I use the below approach to achieve the vertical scaling you are looking for.

- **Step 1**: Create an Automation account
- **Step 2**: Create a PowerShell Runbook in the automation account you created in previous step. This script would scale up your app service
  plan
- **Step 3**: Create an alert rule using the Azure Monitor for your criteria. say, alert
  to be fired when Memory usage % is more that 40% or CPU utilization more than 5%)
  [image]
- **Step 4**: Create an action group that will invoke a runbook you created in
  **Step #2**
  [image]
- **Step 5**: Associate this action group to the alert you have created in **Step #3**.
  [image]

This will do what you are looking for. when the memory utilization is over 40% the alert is triggered which in turn will call you runbook to scale up your app service plan.

You can refer to my article [here](https://medium.com/@pasupathy.guru/scheduling-vertical-scaling-using-microsoft-azure-automation-accounts-af318aad0851?source=friends_link&sk=87861f07c0c7c42ffff80ffb129e0389) for detailed description of how to create an automation account and also for the PowerShell script to scale up an app service plan